# Trying to render a grease pencil animation, but the render result is unclean

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil

I am trying to render a simple animation in blender, the idea is to make clean lineart in blender, export it to another program and then do the colouring and the rest there.

But rendering out the animation using line art modifier wacky things happen.

The first few frames are fine, but at about the middle point the line art starts to flicker and at one point straight up breaks.

I've tried to increase render quality, I've rebaked the grease pencil modifier twice, and also checked if motion blur was on, no progress.

I wish I could send the file and the animation for clarity but I can't seem to be able to.

[image: Completely unusable frame of the animation]

Comment: If your blend file is under 30Meg in size you can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to add the link to it into your question.

Comment: Unfortunately it's bigger then that

Comment: You'll need to use an external site such as Google Drive (just as an example) in that case and share a link to it.

Comment: Here, thanks for all the help so far, I hope anyone can tell me what's up with this, ttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z9dI5_ETSScsu03ABGZxX24flTFyVMZD/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: You'll need to allow access to your file. Once one has added an 'h' to the start of that link and removed the closing bracket from the end, you end up on a page requesting access to your file... I suggest you either delete your original question and start again or add the corrected link directly into your question in which case it will be resubmitted automatically so others will see it.